# Learn unit test from zero in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing

Are there books or articles that teach to write unit test in ruby ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Rails guide to testing is pretty good: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want write tests using 'test/unit' the WikiBooks has article about it http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Unit_testing. But there are more testing frameworks for Ruby like RSpec, then look at http://rspec.info/.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a book for Ruby, http://majesticseacreature.com/rbp-book/pdfs/rbp_1-0.pdf is a nice source of information on Ruby written by Matz himself. It covers each topic in TDD
Rails documentation is obviously targets things mostly around Rails, I would recommend reading about Ruby over Rails.

Comment: A great book, but it was written by Greg Brown - Matz provided the foreword. I agree that reading about Ruby in general is a better bet than focusing too tightly on Rails.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use test::unit or rspec? For rspec best way of learning - The Rspec Book ([The spec book](http://pragprog.com/book/achbd/the-rspec-book))

Answer (score 1):

I can absolutely recommend the investment of buying and reading [The RSpec Book: Behaviour-Driven Development with RSpec, Cucumber, and Friends](http://pragprog.com/book/achbd/the-rspec-book). Apart from all the technical whistles, it will introduce you to an approach to programming that makes sure your code is easily testable, adheres to good design practices and does what your customer thinks it should do.